# Git merge conflict window doesn't show in VSCode (CodeLens)

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-merge-conflict, codelens, vscode-git

I have git version 2.32.0.windows.2, VSCode version 1.68.1 and CodeLens doesn't show up when there are conflicts.

Git recognizes the conflicts but VSCode somehow fails to show me the conflict so I can't manage it with CodeLens.

[image]

The image is not that self explanatory, but it seems like the left part where some code should be shown is empty, and in the original README.md file, the usual UI where you can select which changes to keep and discard is simply not there.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was **isolated** and **solved** once we observed that VSCode was failing **only** on the **readme.md file** and not on other files.

Something was wrong about the file, trying different approaches we found that **changing the readme.md file encoding to UTF-8 solved the problem**. It was *UTF-16LE* before by default.

**Solution**:

1. Select the `README.md` file
2. From the bottom-right corner select the current encoding (click it)
3. A new windows pops up saying "Select Action"
4. Select "Reopen with encoding"
5. Select UTF-8

This solved my issue correctly and didn't find anything online that links directly to what beginners like me might look for, for example "CodeLens" or "Git Conflicts", [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/130179) is an older post directly from GitHub that I found.

*(When you encounter this kind of problem error messages you might search for all link to git problems and not encoding or vscode problems)*

Answer (score 0):

Version: 1.70.2 (Universal)
Commit: e4503b30fc78200f846c62cf8091b76ff5547662
Date: 2022-08-16T05:36:37.829Z
Electron: 18.3.5
Chromium: 100.0.4896.160
Node.js: 16.13.2
V8: 10.0.139.17-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 21.6.0

I faced the same issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).